# WSDL giving an error in Visual Studio 2010. Array syntax incorrect?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have taken over support of a web application and it includes a SOAP web service. The soap server is coded in PHP using SoapServer (http://php.net/manual/en/soapserver.soapserver.php) and works correctly with PHP as the soap client. But now I am trying to use the WSDL in Visual Studio 2010, and although Visual Studio is able to see all the methods defined in the WSDL, when I have attached the web reference the .Net application throws an error when I try to compile. The error that is thrown is as follows:

Custom tool error: Unable to import WebServiceSchema. Unable to import binding 'ApolloSoap' from namespace 'http://clientdomain/soap/export'. Unable to import operation 'getPosts'. The datatype 'http://clientdomain/soap/export/:getPostsArray' is missing.

I will post the source of the WSDL document (Note that I have abridged the source because it is HUGE. I have taken out everything pertaining to other methods in the WSDL to try focus on the method that is reported in the error message.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://clientdomain/soap/export/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" targetNamespace="http://clientdomain/soap/export/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <s:schema targetNamespace="http://clientdomain/soap/export/" elementFormDefault="qualified">
            <s:import namespace="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/"/>
            <s:element name="post">
                <s:complexType>
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Reference" type="s:string"/>
                        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Technician" type="s:string"/>
                        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Customer" type="s:string"/>
                        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Address" type="s:string"/>
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
            <s:element name="getPosts">
                <s:complexType>
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="authorisationcode" type="s:string"/>
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
            <s:element name="getPostsResponse">
                <s:complexType>
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:element name="getPostsArray" type="tns:getPostsArray"/>
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
            <s:element name="getPostsArray">
                <s:complexType>
                    <s:complexContent>
                        <s:restriction base="soapenc:Array">
                            <s:attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="tns:post[]"/>
                        </s:restriction>
                    </s:complexContent>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
        </s:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="getPostsSoapIn">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getPosts"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="getPostsSoapOut">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getPostsResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="ApolloSoap">
        <wsdl:operation name="getPosts">
            <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'>
                    Function ("getPosts")
                </wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="tns:getPostsSoapIn"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:getPostsSoapOut"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:portType name="ApolloSoap12">
        <wsdl:operation name="getPosts">
            <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'>
                    Function ("getPosts")
                </wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="tns:getPostsSoapIn"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:getPostsSoapOut"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="ApolloSoap" type="tns:ApolloSoap">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="getPosts">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://clientdomain/soap/export/getPosts" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:binding name="ApolloSoap12" type="tns:ApolloSoap12">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="getPosts">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="http://clientdomain/soap/export/getPosts" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="wService">
        <wsdl:port name="ApolloSoap" binding="tns:ApolloSoap">
            <soap:address location="http://clientdomain//web/_soap/server.php?pmoaEyLb3BvW0Vwc3jf="/>
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="ApolloSoap12" binding="tns:ApolloSoap12">
            <soap12:address location="http://clientdomain//web/_soap/server.php?pmoaEyLb3BvW0Vwc3jf="/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong with this WSDL document and why .Net is not seeing the definition of *getPostsArray* despite the fact that it is defined in the types section of the document?

UPDATE:

I have a suspicion that the lines causing the problem for visual Studio are the following:

```
<s:restriction base="soapenc:Array">
    <s:attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="tns:post[]"/>
</s:restriction>
```

I suspect these lines because when I create a simple web service in Visual Studio I see that the generated code for the array is as follows:

```
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfPost">
    <s:sequence>   
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Post" nillable="true" type="tns:Post" />
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

Can anyone explain these two different ways of defining an array of a complex type and confirm/deny that the syntax in my WSDL document is incorrect?

Comment: Do you see a `complexType` for `getPostArray`? I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio is telling you the truth. Here's what XMLSpy says:

File Untitled1.wsdl is not valid.
    Invalid XML schema: ''tns:getPostsArray' must refer to an existing simple or complex type.'

Comment: Thanks, John for the reply. I just discovered this too by comparing my WSDL document to one generated by Visual Studio. Basically, I needed to remove the _<s:element name="getPostsArray">_ surrounding the _<s:complexType>_ and then add the name to the complex type so that it reads _<s:complexType name="getPostsArray">_. The same applies to the complex type _post_. Once I made these changes the WSDL worked. :) Thanks for your help on this.